# For loop stop condition for an array that populates dynamically when the code runs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I am creating a navigation list that is populated dynamically whenever new section element is added to the page.
I first created an empty array whose purpose is to receive the contents added on the page continuously by applying a forLoop to it.

**Here is the javascript code**

```
    var list= document.getElementById('navbar__list'); 

let myArray= []; //Create an empty array
for( let i=0; i<=myArray.length; i++){
  var triggerSection= document.getElementById('section'+(1+i)); //Call section elements one by one with id=section(1+i)
  myArray.push(triggerSection); //push elements to create an array that includes all sections on the page
  var sectionName= myArray[i].getAttribute('data-nav'); //Call data-nav value for each item
  const newItem= document.createElement('Li'); //create li elemnt inside the document object
  newItem.textContent= sectionName; //pass the data-nav value as a text to the li element
  newItem.setAttribute('id','item'+(1+i));
  list.appendChild(newItem); //pass the li element to the  unordered list
}
```

**The HTML code**

```
<ul id="navbar__list">


      </ul>

<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
<section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
<section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
```

The problem is that when setting the end condition of the for loop like shown above it adds an extra element to the end of the array with the value of (null) and the console generates that error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null"

and when removing the equal sign to make the end condition as follows (i<myArray.length), the error is no more shown,but the (myArray) created returns to be an empty array, sequentially no items are shown on the navigation bar on the webpage.

Comment: Why are you pushing new elements onto the array _in_ the loop over the array?

Comment: _“populated dynamically whenever new content is added to the page”_ - explain what that actually means. Are you talking about content that gets added on the server side, or on the client side? If the latter, what does that actually look like?

Comment: I don’t see how this process is even supposed to end … you keep selecting elements by ever increasing `sectionX` id value, and even if `getElementById` doesn’t actually return an element any more (because there aren’t any), I don’t see you taking that into account, you just keep on pushing null onto the array …

Comment: This should probably be done using a different approach to begin with. Use `querySelectorAll` to select all of your sections (by a common class, by them being grouped into a common ancestor, whatever) - and then just loop over the resulting NodeList. That should completely eliminate the need to puzzle together dynamic ID values in the first place.

Comment: iI mean that t populates whenever I add a new section element to the HTML file as shown in the HTML file above.

Comment: Okay, then this really doesn’t need that kind of overly complicated “dynamic” approach you attempted here. Go with `querySelectorAll`, and just loop over the result …

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not iterate over an array while you add or remove elements on it. It's in general a risky thing, cause it depends on programming languages and it is hard to understand as well. Better use a *while* or *do-while* loop in this case.

If you want to stay to your for loop you could simply add a break condition.

```
for ( let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    let triggerSection= document.getElementById( 'section' + ( 1 + i ));
    if ( triggerSection === null ) break;
    ...
}
```

Instead a better termination condition of a loop could be `triggerSection === null`, because `getElementById` returns `null` if no element is found. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById )

Therefore this should work:

```
let i = 0;
while ( (let triggerSection = document.getElementById( 'section' + ( 1 + i ))) !== null) {


    i++;
}
```

Comment: _“You should not iterate over an array. It's in general a risky thing.”_ - what!?! Sorry, but that makes very little sense.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works really nice. :D

Comment: Thank you so much @CBroe I tried the querySelector too and it works nice. :D

Comment: @CBroe True. Don't wanted to say that :D Corrected it ;)